# Extend and fill a Pandas DataFrame to match another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, reindex

I have two Pandas DataFrames A and B.

They have an identical index (weekly dates) up to a point: the series ends at the beginning of the year 
 for A and goes on for a number of observations in frame B. I need to set data frame A to have the same index as frame B - and fill each column with its own last values.

Thank you in advance.

Tikhon

EDIT: thank you for the advice on the question. What I need is for dfA_before to look at dfB and become dfA_after:

```
print(dfA_before)
a    b
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300

print(dfB)
    a    b
0  11  111
1  22  222
2  33  333
3  44  444
4  55  555

print(dfA_after)
    a    b
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300
3  30  300
4  30  300
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Try `df_out = df_a.combine_first(df_b)`

Comment: @Poudel I'm not sure what I can do there - other than describe it...

Comment: @scottBoston. Thanks for the suggestion ut all that does is it appends the data frames by columns.  I need to resize df_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,30],'b':[100,200,300]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[11,22,33,44,55],'c':[111,222,333,444,555]})

# solution
last = df1.iloc[-1].to_numpy()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(last,(2,1)),
                   columns=df1.columns)

df4 = df1.append(df3,ignore_index=True)

# method 2
for _ in range(len(df2)-len(df1)):
    df1.loc[len(df1)] = df1.loc[len(df1)-1]


# method 3
for _ in range(df2.shape[0]-df1.shape[0]):
    df1 = df1.append(df1.loc[len(df1)-1],ignore_index=True)

# result
    a    b
0  10  100
1  20  200
2  30  300
3  30  300
4  30  300
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried to do just that - see question.

Comment: Thank you very much. It actually doesn't work on mine as I have a date index (i think that's what's gumming up the works) - I messed up with simplifying my example. I've solved this - probably in the junkiest and most inefficient method possible...

Comment: @Tikhon Glad you solved the question and learn something new. In the mean time, if any of the answers here answers your question, you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably very inefficient - I am a beginner:

```
dfA_New = dfB.copy()
dfA_New.loc[:] = 0  
dfA_New.loc[:] = dfA.loc[:]
dfA_New.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
dfA = dfA_New
```